# Java lock and getHoldCount()

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, concurrency, locking

I am confused about the method assert lock.getHoldCount() == 0; The below example is from Java docs, and it says `Returns: the number of holds on this lock by the current thread, or zero if this lock is not held by the current thread`, which I don't quite understand.

```
class X {
      ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
      // ...
   public void m() {
        assert lock.getHoldCount() == 0;
        lock.lock();
        try {
           // ... method body
        } finally {
           lock.unlock();
        }
   }
 }
```

My question is that -

1. can `lock.getHoldCount()`still return a number here, as we have already assert `==0`?
2. does it mean that no thread can enter the lines below `assert lock.getHoldCount() == 0;`, even if it has the lock?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but...

lock.getHoldCount() will always return a non-negative number---the number of "holds" that the calling thread has on the lock.

This code will throw an AssertionError *IF* assertions are enabled:

```
lock.lock();  //sets the hold count > 0, so...
m();          //...the assertion in m() will fail.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code ensures that this method is the first in the hierarchy of calls to hold the lock.

As for why, it's a good question. Maybe the author wanted to avoid a situation like k()->m()->l()->m(), but this is a re-entrant lock, so I'm not sure why the author would want to do that.

Hope this helps.

Slava

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can lock.getHoldCount()still return a number here, as we have already assert == 0?

Yes, this method always return a non-negative integer. The document emphasizes this method *"is typically only used for testing and debugging purposes"*. Also the sentence in the doc said "The number of holds on this lock **by the current thread**", means your debugging thread *t[i]* which calls the method shall return how many holds *t[i]* has on the instance **lock** -> and you dont have idea of *t[j], t[k], ... holds* on the **lock**.

> 2. Does it mean that no thread can enter the lines below assert lock.getHoldCount() == 0; 
>    **Even if** it has the lock?

If you run the JVM with option -ea (enable assertion) -> in case the thread has the lock, shall cause the program throws exception. (wont reach line `lock.lock;`). In contrast without mentioned JVM options, the code flow execution shall by pass the line `assert` and waiting at line `lock.lock;`

Without that option, please ignore the line `assert`